# Cloud Firestore security rules, doesn't work in smartphones

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Querys and updates doesn't work in Smartphone, but yes in emulator (Cloud Firestore)

Cloud Firestore showed a warning:
"The Cloud Firestore database will start rejecting customer requests, unless you update the security rules".

Then queries and updates doesn't work in smartphones, but yes in emulator of Android Studio.

Application need authentication. When the user sign up, data is saved in Authentication but not in Cloud Firestore collection.

My code of security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firestore rules is configured that no one(for users) can modify your Firestore database. If you want only authenticated users that can read and write in your Firestore database you should update your Firestore rules like the example below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    }
}
```

> When the user sign up, data is saved in Authentication but not in Cloud Firestore collection.

This is correct, it is not automatically saved and you should manually save it using your codes. The number of field in Firebase Authentication is limited like email and phone number but you can retrieve it. To add more details for your users, you can use Firestore, create a collection for users and store additional details of users in field like fullname, age and etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have a collection for users that store fullname, age, etc, and other collections. Users are stored in Authentication, but not in Cloud Firestore on smartphones. In emulator of Android Studio, yes. I was test this rules but don't work too. I will try now.